# Another IE Issue with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Alright, This code works in every browser except IE (again, to be expected). The code is supposed to refresh based on setInterval, and does so normally in all other browsers except IE, which just doesn't refresh. Can you spot the problem?

```
var nick = document.getElementById("chatnick").value;
var sessid = document.getElementById("sessid").value;
var room = document.getElementById("roomid").value;
function user_read() {
  $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "methods.php",
 data: {method: "u", room: room},
 dataType: "html",
 success: function (data, status, xhr) {
     $("#userwindow").html(data);
     setTimeout(user_read, 10000);
 }
});
}
function ajax_read() {
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "methods.php",
 data: {method: "r", room: room},
 dataType: "html",
 success: function (data, status, xhr) {
     $("#chatwindow").html(data);
     setTimeout(ajax_read, 400);
 }
});
}
function submit_msg() {
var msg = document.getElementById("chatmsg").value;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "methods.php",
    data: {method: "w", room: room, m: msg, n: nick, sessid: sessid},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    }
});
document.getElementById("chatmsg").value = "";
}
function keyup(arg1) { 
if (arg1 == 13) submit_msg(); 
}
setTimeout(function(){ajax_read();}, 400);
user_read();
```

Comment: why don't you use setInterval in the DOM ready event instead of setTimeout(). Also set cash: false in the ajax settings.

Comment: Because, I'm new to JS and jQuery, and do not how to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Setting cache: false doesn't do anything to IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a caching issue, try using POST instead of GET. In fact, use post everywhere if you can as **IE doesn't cache POST requests/responses**.

Also, you clear the message sent before the ajax function has completed, seems fishy. Try rewriting like this:

```
function submit_msg() {
var msg = $("#chatmsg").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "methods.php",
    data: {method: "w", room: room, m: msg, n: nick, sessid: sessid},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        $("#chatmsg").val("");
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Sending isn't the issue, it's updating the user_read and ajax_read divs.

Comment: It would appear that IE is caching the divs, how do I prevent it from doing that. POST doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Use post everywhere, IE doesn't cache POST requests/responses. - http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a problem I've run across in IE using AJAX.  Have you tried appending something to URLs to make them unique?  For instance, a random integer as a param.